# How to count files with 2 types of extensions in a directory in python?

Tags: python

I have a directory with several types of files.
How can I count the number of files in a directory with 2 types of extensions (.txt and .csv)?
In my search I found how to count with only one certain extension

Comment: use `os.walk(dir)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to filter the filename:

```
import os
import re

txt_or_csv = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if re.search(r'.*\.(txt|csv)$', f)]

print(len(txt_or_csv))
```

Answer (score 4):

Assume `path` is the path to your folder. Then

```
import os

# get list of files
list_of_files = os.listdir(path)

# txt files
num_txt = len([x for x in list_of_files if x.endswith(".txt")])
# csv files
num_csv = len([x for x in list_of_files if x.endswith(".csv")])
```

Answer (score 4):

A better variant of Yilun answer (which is already nice since it doesn't scan the directory twice like `len(glob.glob("*.csv"))` and `len(glob.glob("*.txt"))` would do for instance).

That one doesn't create an extra list (faster) using `sum` (booleans are summed as 0 or 1) and a generator comprehension:

```
import os

# get list of files
list_of_files = os.listdir(path)

# txt files
num_txt = sum(x.endswith(".txt") for x in list_of_files)
# csv files
num_csv = sum(x.endswith(".csv") for x in list_of_files)
```

gencomps+sum is cool, but it still loops/tests twice on `list_of_files`. Good old loop isn't that bad after all (at least it scans once and shortcuts):

```
num_txt, num_csv = 0,0
for x in list_of_files:
   if x.endswith(".txt"):
      num_txt += 1
   elif x.endswith(".csv"):
      num_csv += 1
```

BTW to count both at the same time, use the tuple param capability of `endswith`

```
# csv & txt files
num_txt_csv = sum(x.endswith((".csv",".txt")) for x in list_of_files)
```

Comment: you mean python 3.6 ? there's a `scandir` backport module for earlier versions.

Comment: this "more efficient" thing for `scandir`/`walk`/whatever is faster for a very special set of circumstances: 1) windows 2) if you need to perform a `stat` on the object. In other cases, it's not faster. Besides, the question is about "files in a directory". `walk` scans subdirs as well (and so it's slower)